# Extend ASP.Net MVC Website with IronPython

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ironpython

is it possible to extend an existing ASP.Net MVC Website, written in C#, with IronPython. I want to make our website customizable. So my plan was, i can write additional controller and models in IronPython and views with "cshthml" and then load it dynamically in the website.

I've searched a lot and found some examples, but they always work with ASP.Net Web Forms.

Thank you!

Comment: You can most certainly do this in MVC.  I implemented a solution allowing developers to create their own AutoComplete controllers using IronPython.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two pages found on Google help explain it in depth.

http://www.tikalk.com/net/write-aspnet-mvc-using-ironpython-resources
http://forums.asp.net/t/1527861.aspx?how+to+start+ironpython+in+asp+net

You will need to add a reference to the DLL in your references section of the project. Other than that, things should work as normal. I use IronPython in my business website without any issues whatsoever. If you get it running and find that there is a piece of code you are having trouble with, please don't hesitate to comment.